# Android app testing - Multiple Cucumber scenarios on the same session of the device

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium-android, automation-testing

I am performing Android tests using Appium-Cucumber-TestNG framework.

I have a feature file which 1 Scenario with multiple tests.

[image: Feature file example]

Now, if I run this test, it will launch the app 3 times for the 3 tests.

Is there a way that I could launch the app once and in the same session run all the 3 tests?